# Extend the set of reloadable directories on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, catalina

I would like to extend the set of reloadable directories on tomcat 7.0.59.
When reloadable attribute within `Context` is set to true, tomcat monitors classes in: `/WEB-INF/classes/` and `/WEB-INF/lib`.

> Set to true if you want Catalina to monitor classes in
>   /WEB-INF/classes/ and /WEB-INF/lib for changes, and automatically
>   reload the web application if a change is detected. This feature is
>   very useful during application development, but it requires
>   significant runtime overhead and is not recommended for use on
>   deployed production applications. That's why the default setting for
>   this attribute is false. You can use the Manager web application,
>   however, to trigger reloads of deployed applications on demand.

Entire system is divided into modules, each module can have its own web context (`/WEB-INF/classes/`) and/or extend the global context (`/classes/`). Let's say that I'd like to have `/classes/` directory reloadable. How can I achieve that?

I tried using `WatchedResource` tag, without effect:

```
<Context reloadable="true" path="/test" docBase="/MY_MODULE/web/webroot">
     <Manager pathname="" />
     <WatchedResource>/MY_MODULE/classes</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

Comment: Why do you *have* a `/classes/` directory that isn't `/WEB-INF/classes/`?

Comment: It's a very large project's specific "feature".

Comment: Have you tried to add a soft link in your file system?

Comment: No, but I'm looking for a solution on tomcat configuration side

Comment: Saying it's a 'feature' doesn't constitute an answer to the question. What is the reason for the 'feature'? *Considering it isn't supported by Tomcat,* it isn't a 'feature' at all, it is a *bug.* If those classes were in `WEB-INF/classes` you wouldn't have a problem, or a question to answer.

Comment: Entire system is divided into modules, each module can have its own web context (`/WEB-INF/classes`) and/or extend the global context (`/classes`). I will try to modify `CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml` then.

Comment: @luke Classes to support 'global context' should be put into JAR files in Tomcat's `lib` directory. You can't just invent a feature and then expect Tomcat to support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try starting tomcat with HotSwapAgent: [Plugin_tomcat.](http://hotswapagent.org/mydoc_plugin_tomcat.html)
([GITHUB HotswapProjects](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent))

You can have a differrent `hotswap-agent.properties` file on each of your modules, to load differrent classpaths.